# Passing parameters from Java to Groovy in SOAPUI

Tags: groovy, soapui

I have a java program as below,

```
   package test;
class HelloWorld {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Hi");
    String a="World";
  }
}
```

And groovy script as below,

```
    import test.HelloWorld
HelloWorld.main(null)
```

And I am using this groovy script in SOAPUI after keeping the jar file in /bin/ext SOAPUI folder.

I am able to execute this groovy script in console.

But my requirement is,I need to pass variable say "a" in java program in SOAPUI test input.

For eg:
Add test input in soapui

```
<add>
<a> "Variable a" </a>
<b>5</b>
</add>
```

I want to refer that variable coming out of java program in this test input.Please let me know the way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Java* and *Groovy* integrates smooth. However to access the `String a` value `a` must be and attribute in object not a variable in a method. Let me explain; in your case for example in the *Java* part instead of a `main` method create an *object* like:

```
package test;
class HelloWorld {

  private String a;
  public HelloWorld(){
     this.a = "World";
  }

  public String getA(){
     return this.a;
  }
}
```

Compile and add the jars to `SOAPUI_HOME/bin/ext`.

Then from *groovy script* in SOAPUI you can instantiate the class and get the value:

```
import test.HelloWorld
def a = new HelloWorld().getA()
log.info a // this prints --> World
```

If besides you want to use this value in a request you've to set the property value at some test level (for example in *testCase*):

```
import test.HelloWorld
def a = new HelloWorld().getA()
log.info a // this prints --> World
testRunner.testCase.setPropertyValue('myVar',a)
```

Now that your variable is set you can use the follow notation to use it in your requests: `${#TestCase#myVar}`, in your request sample:

```
<add>
<a>${#TestCase#myVar}</a>
<b>5</b>
</add>
```

Hope it helps,

Comment: Nice and simple example.

Comment: Wonderful explanation..Thankyou :)

Comment: @rk4 nice to help you `:)`